# Azure SSO unable to get user info by access token

Tags: azure, single-sign-on

I'm trying to implement Azure SSO in my SPA application. So fare I'm able to authenticate user and as a response I get back access token.

[image]

After that I'm trying to get user base profile by this url:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

With Authorise as Bearer token. But some reason as a response I get following error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "UnknownError",
        "message": "",
        "innerError": {
            "date": "2023-08-31T09:55:43",
            "request-id": "eaf36ab5-aba3b1",
            "client-request-id": "eaf36ab5-aba3-49b1"
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know what going wrong.
Is there something wrong in App setting on azure?
Please check my current settings:

[image]
[image]

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The error occurred as your token don't have **User.Read** permission in **`scp`** claim that is mandatory for reading user info.

I registered one Azure AD application and added `User.Read` permission as below:

[image]

Now, I generated tokens using **authorization code** flow via Postman with below parameters:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id: <app_ID>
grant_type:authorization_code
scope: openid profile
code: code
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
client_secret: <secret>
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to get user information, I too got **same error** as below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

**Response:**

[image]

> To resolve the error, make sure to generate **access token** with **`User.Read`** scope.

I got below consent screen when I ran authorization request with **`User.Read`** scope in browser:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 
client_id=appId
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_type=code  
&response_mode=query  
&scope= openid profile User.Read
&state=12345
```

[image]

After consenting the above prompt, I got **authorization code** successfully in address bar:

[image]

Now, I used this code to generate access token with **`User.Read`** scope and got tokens like this:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token
client_id: <app_ID>
grant_type:authorization_code
scope: openid profile
code: code
redirect_uri: https://jwt.ms
client_secret: <secret>
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to get user info, I got **response** successfully like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me
```

**Response:**

[image]

In your case, make sure to pass **`User.Read`** in **scope** parameter.