# Potman Graph API beta: EnterpriseEntityNotFound - Not found (404)

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, postman, http-status-code-404

I want to access the user's profile, with which I created the account and acquired the subscription.I don't know why it can't find profile data

I recovered the token using data from an application record that I created by checking the "only accounts in this organizational directory" option. Under "API permissions" I assigned the necessary permissions.
Token request:
[image]
[image]

My failed request:
[image]

Comment: Could you confirm whether that user exists in same tenant from which you generated access token?

Comment: Looks like wrong userId. I get the same exception when calling /users/{wrong_user_id}/profile

Answer (score 0):

> I agree with *@user2250152*, the error usually occurs if you are passing
> **wrong user ID** or user ID of **different** tenant for fetching profile details.

I registered one Azure AD application and added **`User.Read.All`** permission as below:

[image]

Now, I generated **access token** using client credentials flow via Postman like this:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appId
client_secret: secret 
scope: https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

I used this token to get user's profile which is not present in that tenant and got **same error** as below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<userID>/profile
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I passed **`userID`** of same tenant, I got **response** with profile details successfully like below:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/<userID>/profile
```

**Response:**

[image]

In your case, make sure to pass **`userID`** of same tenant from which you generated the access token.

Comment: Of course I have all that done but I don't know if I should do something with the created users

Comment: What do you mean by created users? Could you include how you created those users?

Comment: I mean I do the steps mentioned before and create the users from: Active Directory Main Menu > "Users
But I don't know if something else needs to be done with the users
Do these users have to be assigned to the application registry?

Comment: There is no need to assign those users to application registry. Are you still getting same error in fetching profiles of those created users? Do you have multiple directories in your account?

Comment: No, I only have the base created directory. I don't quite understand this part... I run https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/profile and it returns a 404 Not found.

Comment: Could you try running same query https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/profile in [**Graph Explorer**](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer) by signing in with that [user](https://i.imgur.com/r2UYRKT.png) and check if you getting 
**same error** or not?

Comment: Of course it works in graph explorer, but what could it be? In Postman the token is good and it returns the 404

Comment: In Postman. you need to use delegated flow like authorization code flow or username password flow etc... for generating access token. It won't work if the token is of client credentials flow.

Comment: I am generating the token by delegated access. The configuration is what comes in the Delegated > Authorization folder https://www.postman.com/microsoftgraph/workspace/microsoft-graph/collection/455214-085f7047-1bec-4570-9ed0-3a7253be148c

Comment: Could you try creating token separately using **authorization code** flow by following this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77014771/azure-sso-unable-to-get-user-info-by-access-token/77015441#77015441) that I previously answered?